# Is there any way to find the value of a cell in excel depending on the font colour by Using ExcelJs in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, excel, exceljs

**Is there any way to find the value of a cell in excel depending on the font colour by Using ExcelsJs in NodeJS**

for **example,** I want to get all values inside an excel where they are colour font is grey

I am using a Nodejs, with exceljs
**if there any suggesting, I will be very thankful
this photo from one sheet where I need to find a solution**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they don't have a special method to search a certain cells y different criteria but you can do it yourself by iterating all cells like this:

```js
const rows = worksheet.getRows(1, worksheet.rowCount)

const foundCells = []
for (const row of rows) {
  const cells = row.
  for (let cIndex = 1; cIndex <= worksheet.columnCount; cIndex++) {
    const cell = row.getCell(cIndex);
    if (cell.font.bold) {
      foundCells.push(cell);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I found the colour of each cell depending on the index of colour inside the font object